# Dispatch in middleware leads to action with wrong type

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a simple middleware to handle socket events.

```
const join = (channel) => (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({
  type: 'ACTION-1',
  socketChannel: {...},
  events: [...],
 });
};
```

I dispatch this action that triggers it. And now when the dispatch method was called in my middleware with type 'ACTION-2' and received socketData as a payload, I see in my console what 'ACTION-1' was triggered twice and in the last time it is came with my socketData payload.

I wonder why 'ACTION-1' was registered instead 'ACTION-2' and how I can fix it? I would appreciate your help.

```
import { socket } from 'services/socket';

const socketMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => (action) => {
  const {
    channel,
    events, // an array of events for the channel
    ...rest
  } = action;


  if (typeof action === 'function' || !channel) {
    return next(action);
  }

  const {
    type,
    name,
  } = channel;


  const channelInstance = socket.instance[type](name);

  events.forEach((event) => {
    const handleEvent = (socketData) => {
      dispatch({ type: 'ACTION-2', socketData, ...rest });
    };
    channelInstance.listen(event.name, handleEvent);
  });

  return next(action);
};

export {
  socketMiddleware
};
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are not pathing the channel in your initial dispatch and you are failing your middleware finishes inside this if:

```
if (typeof action === 'function' || !channel) {
  return next(action);
}
```

in order to fix this you should add channel in your dispatch:

```
const join = (channel) => (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({
  type: 'ACTION-1',
  socketChannel: {...},
  events: [...],
  channel: { type: '...', name: '...' }
 });
};
```